# Keep element position after reload page - drag and drop cdk Angular 7

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I'm using cdk Drag & Drop from Angular 7, but now i'm stuck. When I reload the page, all the items that was organized keep going back to the original position. How can I save the position and retrieve they to the elements?

For now, this is what I have:

**Parent of Pie**

```
<div class="pie-content">
  <div class="individual-pie"  *ngFor="let pie of serials">
    <app-pie [serialnumber]="pie"></app-pie>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Pie.html**

```
<div
  cdkDragBoundary=".content"
  cdkDrag
  (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnd($event)"
  class="pie"
  [chart]="pie"
></div>
```

**Pie.ts**

```
dragEnd(event: CdkDragEnd) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: Save the positioning in local storage.

Comment: But how? I read all the documentation about cdk and cannot get de position of the element (related to the page). And how can I retrieve the position?

Comment: Use trackBy https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#change-propagation

Answer (score 0):

You can save your list to the local storage.
This is how you use it on the page:

```
[chart]="pie"
```

and in your controller:
    @Input
    pie: string[];

so each time you drag and drop, save the list:

```
dragEnd(event: CdkDragEnd) {
  console.log(event);
  let myStorage = window.localStorage;
  myStorage.setItem("pie", pie);
}
```

and on refresh get the list from local storage:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let myStorage = window.localStorage;
    this.pie= myStorage.getItem("pie"));
  }
```

Comment: I got: Can't bind to 'cdkDropListData' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("<div

Comment: You are missing: import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop'; in app.module.ts
Anyways, where are the items coming from to populate your pie?

Comment: I edited my question, I have a parent with a *ngFor that call the component 'app-pie'. Already imported DragDropModule

Comment: But my "pie" variable must be of Chart type. I'm using Highcharts

Comment: I don't know how it works but you can save the object as well